# In aws pinpoint (NodeJS) how to trigger a email when custome event trigger by user

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I am working on a NodeJs API which send a mail when New user added in AWS Pinpoint.
I need to trigger a mail when new user add in AWS Pinpoint or sign-in attempts or some transaction happens or credit in his/her account is less than 5.

I have already created a API which add and update user in AWS pinpoint as endpoints.But I stuck in, how to create a custom event which automatically do this task after updating the endpoint in AWS pinpoint.

I have referred https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html link while trying to create custom event. But no proper solution found

Comment: hi, did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you should only send an event, in the EndpointUser part of the payload, put your new user details, it will update the endpoint and will fire event, which you can catch with a campaign